# ¿Cómo calcular el total en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

tengo la siguiente información en una tabla de MySQL, lo que necesito es calcular el total sumando el resultado de multiplicar la cantidad por el precio correspondiente.

En caso de que `Precio con descuento` sea diferente de `NULL` se utilizará para poder hacer el cálculo.

```
| Cantidad   | Precio | Precio con descuento |
|------------|--------|----------------------|
| 1          | 10     | NULL                 |
| 2          | 10     | 5                    |
| 10         | 2      | 1                    |
```

```
1 * 10 = 10

2 * 5 = 10

10 * 1 = 10

TOTAL: 30
```

Actualmente tengo:

```sql
SELECT cantidad, precio, precio_descuento FROM ventas WHERE cerrado = 1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `coalesce()` para multiplicar por uno u otro.

```
select   cantidad
       , precio
       , precio_descuento
       , cantidad * coalesce(precio_descuento, precio) total
  from ventas
 where cerrado = 1;
```

La función `coalesce()` puede recibir N parámetros y te devuelve el valor del primer parámetro que no sea `null`. En este caso, te devolverá el valor de `precio_descuento` si no es `null`, y si lo es, el valor de `precio`.

Otra posibilidad es utilizar una sentencia `case` para determinar cual campo utilizar:

```
select   cantidad
       , precio
       , precio_descuento
       , cantidad * case 
                      when precio_descuento is null then precio 
                      else precio_descuento 
                    end total
  from ventas
 where cerrado = 1;
```

Finalmente, puedes utilizar una función `if()` para lograr el mismo resultado

```
select   cantidad
       , precio
       , precio_descuento
       , cantidad * if(precio_descuento is null, precio, precio_descuento) total
  from ventas
 where cerrado = 1;
```

Si quieres el total de todas las ventas, aplica la función de agregado `sum()` sobre este valor calculado, por ejemplo:

```
select   sum(cantidad * coalesce(precio_descuento, precio)) TotalVentas
  from ventas
 where cerrado = 1;
```